# Get application path in dll

Tags: c++, dll, wxwidgets

My host application was developed using wxWidgets and i need the app path in a pure C++ dll.
If i'm developing a executable application i can get the application path from argv[0].
But, if i'm developing a dll how can i get the application path using just C++? Is it possible?

Comment: Strange question.  If it is a pure C++ dll, why have you tagged it- wxWidgets?

Comment: @ravenspoint I'm linking the dll in a wxwidgets application. Maybe there's a way to exchange information between the host and the library. So I mentioned wxwidgets.

Comment: You should edit your question so that it explains what you are really asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wish to obtain the application path in the host ( and pass it into the DLL code unsing a method ), then you can use the windows API  GetModuleFileName() as suggested by other answerers.  Alternatively, you might use the wxWidgets method wxStandardPaths::[GetExecutablePath](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.9.3/classwx_standard_paths.html#aca76479d42511c0b45f39b0cfbb35c6b)()

Answer (score 4):

Since you mention .dll, you are most likely developing a Windows .dll. If you want the path of the .exe using your .dll, call [`GetModuleFileName(NULL, ...)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683197%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). If you want the path of the .dll, you can pass in the `HINSTANCE` parameter passed to `DllMain` instead.